# Connect qml object property changes to signal/slot mechanism

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I got this basic project:

### main.qml

```
    Rectangle{
            Text {
            id: text1
            objectName: "showStr"
            property string _textField: "passive"
            text: _textField
        }
        Button{
            id: _button
            signal buttClick(string str)
            anchors.top: text1.bottom
            text: "Button"
            onClicked:
            {
                _button.buttClick("state: active")
            }

        }
    }
```

### myClass.cpp

```cpp
class myClass : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myClass(QObject *parent = nullptr): QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void setTextProperty(const QString& s) {this->str = s;}
    void getStrToQObj()
    {
        //TODO: set updated str into qml
    }

 
signals:
    void strChanged(const QString& time);
private:
    QString str;
};
```

### main.cpp

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlComponent component(&engine, 
    QUrl(QLatin1String("../myProj/qml/main.qml")));
    QObject* item = component.create();
    QObject* showTime = item->findChild<QObject*>("showTime");
    QObject* butt = item->findChild<QObject*>("start");

    myClass mc(item);
    QObject::connect(butt, SIGNAL(buttClick(QString)),
                     &mc, SLOT(setTextProperty(QString)));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Connection of Qml signal **buttClick** to **setTextProperty(const QString& s)** works fine and **myClass::str** is changed.The question is how to connect **Text** property *_textField* to update every time, when **myClass::str** is changed?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: add main also, to provide full code, exclude **#include** libraries

Comment: If you have an answer then write it in the answer section. Please read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Comment: oh, no problem. but it would be much easier if you are note edit my question section, so i can copy-paste answer

Comment: no, I am not responsible for your answer

Comment: sorry then, but who did rollback?

Comment: I did the rollback because you are placing the answer in an inappropriate part and then I told you to place it in the answers section as indicated by the SO rules.

Answer (score 2):

Do not export objects from QML to C++, instead do the opposite: export the C ++ objects to QML since this way the connection is simple and there is no need to use the old connection syntax:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    myClass mc;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mc", &mc);

    QQmlComponent component(&engine, 
    QUrl(QLatin1String("../myProj/qml/main.qml")));
    QObject* item = component.create();

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
Rectangle {
    Text {
        id: text1

        text: "passive"
    }

    Button {
        id: _button

        anchors.top: text1.bottom
        text: "Button"
        onClicked: {
            mc.setTextProperty("state: active");
        }
    }

    Connections {
        function onTimeChanged(text) {
            text1.text = text;
        }

        target: mc
    }

}
```

Comment: Idea of project is to separate logic from GUI, so all manipulation must be called in C++ files. In QML i can only show changes, but not make it through JS

Comment: @KostiantynZinchuk mmm, for me my answer fulfills that (although in your post you don't mention anything about separating the implementations). The logic can continue to be implemented in C ++ and you would only make the connections (which are more readable) in QML. Using the old connection method brings many problems since it is only known that it failed in runtime instead of the new syntax that you know in compile time.

Comment: since JS code is not "tested to work fine" in QML, for ones, who do not know it well, it can cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is old syntax of connection, but according to separations logiv from GUI, and for ones who do not know JS well,turns out you can call **parent()** method to you class because it is inherit QObject class. This return to you **Qobject*** you put in constructor of your class, and then you can **findChild** and work with it:

```cpp
void myClass::f(){
    //do fancy stuff with your myClass::str
    emit activityChanged(this->parent())
}
void getStrToQObj(QObject* qo)
{
    auto tmp = qo->findChild<QObject*>("showTime");
    tmp->setProperty("_textField", this->str);
}
```

And connect this in **main.cpp** like:

```cpp
QObject::connect(&mc, SIGNAL(strChanged(QObject*)),
                 &mc, SLOT(getStrToQObj(QObject*)));
```